# C# Driver Aggregation to get filtered embedded document array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I applied the following aggregation to my collection

```
db.getCollection('TypeOfCA').aggregate({$match: {"TypeName": "Mobile"}}, {$unwind: "$Attribute"}, {$match: {"Attribute.Name": {$in: ["Make","Color"]}}})
```

and get the following result,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593fe6bf4b21d9859783eb9f"),
    "TypeName" : "Mobile",
    "TypeCode" : "A",
    "Attribute" : {
        "Name" : "Make",
        "Variables" : [ 
            "Samsung", 
            "Nokia", 
            "Apple"
        ]
    }
}    

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593fe6bf4b21d9859783eb9f"),
    "TypeName" : "Mobile",
    "TypeCode" : "A",
    "Attribute" : {
        "Name" : "Color",
        "Variables" : [ 
            "Red", 
            "White", 
            "Green", 
            "Orange"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Now How can I apply it using C# mongo driver I need the same result, in my C# code**

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/linq/

Comment: Also noting that the above query is actually the worst way possible to retrieve the result.

Comment: thanks that's what I wanted exactly, though that's not the exact query I need to use I just wanted to know how to do those kinds in c# using linq...